# Sheets Formula Works with Iterative Calculations but data gets very messy very fast (with GIF)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, textjoin

Picture: [Sheet Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtMV3.png)

---

OVERALL EXPLANATION OF DOCUMENT AND WHAT IS WHAT:

I have a Google Sheet document (Picture ↑) with

- Products (Product Category and Name) - Columns B:D
- Prices (Weight, Prices with VAT and without, Packaging) - F:Q
- Additional Info (Manufacturer, Supplier, et.c) - Column R, S and next ones

From time to time for example as it is visible in the Row 7, I need MAX PRICE for all the same products.
I achieved that with formulas:
Picture: [F7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJE1t.png)
Picture: [N7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzPDh.png)

These two formulas work and does everything I need. So no problem here.

---

THE PROBLEM

The Problem sits in R7 and S7 (I highlighted them in picture named "Sheet Document").

I found formula that works:
`=SUBSTITUTE(textjoin(", ",true,unique(filter(R4:R,$C$4:$C=$C7))),", 0","")`
It combines all unique Column R values that mathces all the C7 values.

This is how formula should look like.
Picture [How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5847N.png)

Problema is - it works only with Iterative Calculation - ON.

Why it is a problem?

Each time I want to add this formula to another cell (I'm planning to add it manually, because there are specific instances where I need to know combined info about the specific product), it duplicates everything (See GIF below) ↓

GIF: [GIF - Problem - Duplicating](https://imgur.com/a/6Bcxmag.gif)

I think it is because of Iterative Calculation, I have never seen any formula act this way before.

What can be done here?

- Maybe use other formula for R7, S7?
  I have tried a lot of - Vlookup, Index-Match, Query, the only one that worked exactly as I wanted was Substitude-Textjoin-Filter, but yeah, Iterative Calculation meses it up.
- Maybe I need to change all the other formulas?
  I know that with the Circular Dependency Error, you should look for overlapping formulas. In the OVERALL EXPLANATION section you can see how other formulas in the same row are made. I couldn't figure out the one that was overlapping.
- Maybe some App Script can solve this?
  I'm very new to scripts, have used in some documents, including this one, I am open to using them, just need little bit more explanation.

I tried a lot of different formulas, tried to solve Iterative Calculation glitch, changing formulas in other cells so they are not overlapping.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a mix of [absolute and relative references](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/), like this:

```
=textjoin(", ", true, unique( filter(R$4:R6, C$4:C6 = C7) ) )
```

The formula should go into cell `R7`. You should turn off iterative calculation if you can.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this works on the R column and on other Columns and Rows too. Thank you for your time and suggestion :)